# XML file to Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

Здравствуйте. Требуется создать xml и записать не данные а сам xml файл в таблицу Oracle. Вычитал что для хранения самого файла в таблице есть типы clob либо xmltype. Создал таблицу с таким полем. И проблема в загрузке туда файла непосредственно кодом.

```
String str = "D:\\file.xml";
XmlTextWriter textWritter = new XmlTextWriter(str, Encoding.UTF8);
textWritter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
textWritter.WriteStartDocument();
textWritter.WriteStartElement("NAME");
textWritter.WriteString(TextBox1.Text);
textWritter.WriteEndElement();
textWritter.Close();
```

Это создание xml файла. И вот как я пытаюсь добавит его в таблицу.

```
con.Open();
OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("insert into test3 (name) VALUES ('" + textWritter + "')", con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Но как я уже понял textWritter не содержит сам файл в себе. Что мне нужно подставить вместо values что бы в таблицу записался именно файл. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: В оракла можно и в XML рерозиторию сохранить. Посмотрите XMLDB. Как это из c# сделать не знаю.

Comment: Вопрос остаётся открытым, если кто то знает как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста. Потому что всё что нагуглил пока что это только как данные из xml считать в таблицу но не сам файл.